# Extracting coeftest results into a data frame

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm trying to extract model coefficients from R into a data frame that I can then combine into one large dataset with some other model results from Stata.

Using `coeftest` from `lmtest`, I tried this:

```
model_1_coef <- lmtest::coeftest(model1, vcov = sandwich::vcovHC)
```

This seems to just create an object of class 'coeftest', and coercing it into a data frame using `as.data.frame` returned the error "cannot coerce class '"coeftest"' to a data.frame.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: try [`broom::tidy()`](https://broom.tidymodels.org/reference/tidy.coeftest.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally used a little workaround:

```
model_1_coef_df <- as.data.frame(model_1_coef[,])
```

or, using `dplyr` syntax:

```
model_1_coef_df <- model_1_coef[,] %>% 
as_tibble() %>%
mutate(variable = rownames(model_1_coef))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lmtest::coeftest(model1, vcov = sandwich::vcovHC)[,] %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "term")
```